# Application Insights with error handling middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have some error handling middleware which swallows any exceptions..

```
 public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
        {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
            }
        }


private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            string error = "";
            string logerror = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = exception });

#if DEBUG
            error = logerror;
            Log.Error(error);
#else
            Log.Error(logerror);
            error = "An unexpected error occurred";
#endif
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(error);

        }
```

I've just started using Application Insights, and whilst I can see that an error has occurred in the failures section, I cant see the stacktrace, and i suspect it is because the middleware is handling it.. can i do something to display all exception related stuff in application insights?

Comment: If you're logging using the ILogger netcore interface, make sure you use the overload that takes the exception object, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.logcritical?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggerExtensions_LogCritical_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILogger_System_Exception_System_String_System_Object___. The libraries that send the logs off to AI depend on the exception object to create 'Exception Telemetry'. May not be the cause of this, but is generally good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Add [TrackException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient.trackexception?view=azure-dotnet) in your handler function.
2. Log stack trace as well and add an adapter which uploads logs (by default up to warning)

Answer (score 1):

When sending an exception to `ILogger` using [`Log.Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.logerror?view=aspnetcore-2.2) there are two main options:

1. Sending a string
2. Send the `Exception` object and a string

[The results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger) in Application Insights are very different. The first, which you are using, creates a [`TraceTelemetry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.tracetelemetry?view=azure-dotnet) object. The second creates an [`ExceptionTelemetry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.exceptiontelemetry?view=azure-dotnet) object which is designed to hold exception info, including the stack trace.